# How to move many Outlook items from Personal Folder to Mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Our IT Department previously recommended users use Personal Folders when your Mailbox is full.  Now they upgraded their Exchange server and are trying to get rid of PSTs and asking users to move their items back to the server Mailbox.

I have a complex folder structure with many subfolders.  Auto-archive was previously set move items older than 6 months to the personal folder.  So the Personal Folder folder structure and the mailbox structure are the same.

Is there a better way to move these items from Personal Folder to Mailbox besides just going in every folder, selecting all the emails, then dragging them to the appropriate folder in the Mailbox.

There are so many folders that this would take hours to do manually.  Thanks

Comment: The only way to move the files from a local file onto the server is to transfer them which involves dragging and dropping the folder. You can drag the Root folder within your `Local Archive Folder` to save time.

Answer (score 1):

Which outlook are you using? Assuming you are running outlook 2010, you can go to account settings\data files and take note of where the PST actually is, remove the data file from your profile, go to File\Open, then Import, then Import from another program or file, then select Outlook Data file (.PST), then navigate to the location you noted from earlier and specify what to do with duplicates, then tell it where to import to and to include subfolders on the next page, then finish. It'll import the PST to the same folder structure if the folders already exist, or create as necessary.

Comment: When you **Import** do you mean there is an **Import** option because I don't see it myslf hence my suggestion about just dragging and dropping.

Comment: On outlook 2010 Import is located under Open. In other versions, it is located elsewhere. If you go to Help, or help/about outlook, it should tell you which version of outlook you are using, then we can give you the specific location of 'Import' in your version.

Comment: I swear I followed your instructions a second time and the "Open Calendar", "Open Outlook Data File", "Import", and "Other User's Folder" appeared.  The first time all I got was an open file dialog.